Dual of a complete lattice via homset
Suppose $P, Q$ are complete lattices. Define $Hom(P,Q)=\{f\colon P\rightarrow Q\vert f \ \text{preserves arbitrary sups}\}$. Any such $f$ will preserve $0$. And, $P\cong Hom(2,P)$, where $2=\{0,1\}$ is the two-element lattice. I am stuck with the following problem.

Show that $P^{op}$, the dual of the complete lattice $P$ can be represented as $Hom(P,2^{op})$.

